# post form to an iframe on another form (is it possible)

Tags: forms, post, iframe

I'm using ASP.NET web forms and i need to post data to an iframe, the problem is that in web forms I have the main form tag(form1), so i need another form tag(form2), to post data to the iframe that is in the main form1.

Basically i have this:

```
<form method="post" id="form2" action="http://localhost:58903/WebForm1.aspx" target="webApp">
    <input type="hidden" name="ValidationUserName" value="david" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ValidationTokenId" value="13123132132" />
    <button type="submit">Send info to inner iframe</button>
</form> 

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <iframe id="webApp" name="webApp" src="http://localhost:58903/WebForm1.aspx" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></iframe>
        </form>
```

With this approach in open a new tab, if i put the iframe outside it works ok, but if i do this the layout is changed and i don't want this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it, it was missing the "name" attribute in the `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If all the forms are in the same domain you should not work with iframes.
What exactly are you trying to get here? didn't realize completely

Comment: The objective with the iframe is to develop only once the web application and then give to the clients. That's why the iframe, the client will point the iframe "scr" attribute to our app and we need to receive data by post to validate and get process data to be able to work.

Comment: ok then, if your app is running in iframe inside of your client website, the easy way to transfer data to the iframe is in the GET. If you think it's not secure then just know that the POST data can be seen just as the GET, so unless you are sending some realy sensitive information, the GET is a good way. If you need to transfer data from your iframe to the client website it's a bit of a tricky but it's possible, let me know if you need it.